# Is SmartGWT EE's source code available for free?

Tags: smartgwt

Is the source code of SmartGWT Enterprise Edition (SmartGWT EE) available as a free download? I would like to use it in my project.

Answer (score 2):

In a word, no.

> SmartGWT Enterprise Edition (SmartGWT EE for short) is a **commercially licensed version** of SmartGWT that includes Java Server side functionality, additional tools, and a classic commercial license in lieu of the LGPL.

Emphasis mine. Source: http://forums.smartclient.com/showthread.php?t=4839